# What's the exact species of this African Giant Snail?

Tags: species-identification, snail

We've got an African Giant Snail a few years ago but failed to identify the exact species so far. When we got it, it's been about 20 % smaller than now, so it's probably not been an adult snail, but we don't know the exact age.

We only got this single snail, so there's no way to check for the eggs.

Here's a picture (small version, about 400 KiB) and a link to a bigger version. **If you need more detailed pictures of certain parts, please let me know.**

[image: Close-up of the African Giant Snail called Gary-Hildegard of Bingen-Wilson Jr.]

Bigger version: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9z2x.jpg (about 2.2 MiB)

This picture shows that the apex is about 12 centimeters (4.7") in length, while the foot is about 14 centimeters (5.5").

Comment: I try to remember... but are snails not able to lay eggs without another snail?

Comment: Snails are hermaphroditic, so 2 snails will always be able to reproduce, but they aren't autogamous, like e.g. tape worms.

Comment: thank you :) then I mixed this

Answer (score 1):

*I am not sure how to handle this.*

The answer is the content of [**this page**](https://www.petsnails.co.uk/documents/species/arch-and-a-id.html), which (I guess) should not be entirely copy / pasted here for copyright reasons.

So based on the texture of the skin, **you have a variety of Achatina**.

*If I receive advice about how to make this answer comply more with the rules of the site, I will edit my answer.*

Comment: Could it be an **Achatina Fulica**? The sentences "_Though shell coloration may be variable [...], generally it is reddish-brown with light yellowish, vertical (axial) streaks._" & "_There is a wide variety of shell and body polymorphism in snails, perhaps none more than Achatina fulica. **This often leads to it being mistaken for less widespread species.**_" seems to indicate this. I've never been sure of that before, since the apex of Gary not only gets brighter towards the tip, but also more red/pink.

Comment: Of course it can be, but I cannot make any informed claim, other than what I stated already.